# Ember model not saving changes from itemController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, has-many, ember-cli

In a parentController I'm trying to save changes that are made in an itemController. I can see that the model is changed in the store but when I save the model the changes are gone. The team model has a members hasMany relationship and I. All of this happens in a modal dialog.

My code is something similar to this:

```
// editing in the itemController

    .....
    var members = this.get('model.members'),
        currentMember = this.get('activeMember.content'),
        isChecked = this.get('isChecked');

    if (isChecked === true)
        members.pushObject(currentMember);
    else 
        members.removeObject(currentMember);
    .....
```

-

```
// saving in the parentController

    .....
    this.store.find('team').then(function(team){
      team.save();
    }
    .....
```

Comment: Have you checked if the server returns the correct json? If the server does not include the relationsship into the payload, it will be overriden with the "new" truths from the server.

Comment: Yes. The server is returning member id's in each team object. It is a many to none relationship so I've set {inverse: null} on the members attr in the team model.

Comment: Mehh. It had to do with the backend but it didn't throw an error or warning xD